# C- Why can return i == 26 set the limit for how many letters are required in the command line at the end of the function?

Tags: c, command-line, cs50

I recently learned from CS50 that there is needed to set conditions under the command line in substitution.
So below code are two conditions, 1) check input is an alphabet. 2) 26 letter is required in input if less or over should return an error message.

```
bool is_valuekey(string key)
{
    //check if is alphabet
    int i = 0;
    int n = strlen(key);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        char keyno = key[i];
        if (!isalpha (keyno))
        {
            return false;
        
        }
    }
    return i == 26;
}
```

My question is: What purpose does "return i == 26;" in the Boolean "is_valid" serve? I don't understand why the function won't work without it or if u change the number.

below is some testing:

```
~/pset1/substitution/ $ ./substitution 2328 (non alphabet should return error)
Usage: ./substitution key
~/pset1/substitution/ $ ./substitution AIWEFJSKWOSJFG(14 alphabets should return error)
Usage: ./substitution key
~/pset1/substitution/ $ ./substitution AIWEFJSKWOSJFGJWITORSQWE(24 alphabets should return error)
Usage: ./substitution key
~/pset1/substitution/ $ ./substitution AIWEFJSKWOSJFGJWITORSQWEER(26 alphabets,pass to next)
Enter your plain text: 
HI
```

Comment: `i`, which is the same value as `n` at the end of the function, counts how many characters are in the `key` string. It is a requirement that the key must have exactly one character for every letter of the English alphabet. Hence the count of the characters in `key` must be 26. That's what that condition checks for - true if there are 26 characters and false otherwise.

Comment: @kaylum the question doesn't say that the 26 letters in the key must be unique.

Comment: @susanth29 Where in my comment did I say the characters have to be unique? Having 26 of the same letter is still 26 characters. The important part is the count and not what each character is for that check.

Comment: `AIWEFJSKWOSJFGJWITORSQWEER` is exactly one character for each letter in the alphabet. `A` is for `A`, `I` is for `B`, `W` is for `C`, etc. So the key has a character for every letter in the alphabet. That's what I meant.

Comment: @kaylum understood. Although this is generally the case when an input with 26 alphabets is needed, I think it is not good to assume so when it is not mentioned in the question. The OP only said that the input must be of length 26. There was no mention that the `key` is used for substituting the English alphabet.

Answer (score 3):

`return i == 26` return true if i = 26 and return false otherwise. The for loop ends when i == n, so it is another way of checking that there are exactly 26 characters in the `key`. It can also be done before the for loop like this

```
int i = 0;
int n = strlen(key);
if(n != 26) return false;
// for loop 
return true;
```